# kotlin-reflect with proguard causes reflection errors

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, proguard, kotlin-reflect

I'm using ProGuard for my spring boot application code. After I upgraded to Spring Boot 2, I cannot start my application anymore.

Spring Boot 2 uses kotlin-reflect to create beans, which uses `kotlin.Metadata` annotation during reflection. This annotation has unobfuscated values and therefore kotlin-reflect is looking for methods with original names. and following exception is thrown:

`kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: Could not compute caller for function: public constructor ProjectService(...`

`ProjectService` is obfuscated to `F`, hence no such constructor.

When I keep class names, I have same problem elsewhere:

`kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: Could not compute caller for function: public open fun addRole(...`

Is there a way to fix the obfuscation of `kotlin.Metadata` annotation parameters? Annotation itself is not obfuscated and it still refers to original class names which are written as string values. I also tried to obfuscate the Metadata annotation to no avail.

Comment: I started using Gson which doesn't use Kotlin reflection library. But switching to Gson is very inconvenient as it has very different behavior.